# X Server crashes when I start Firefox from chroot

Tags: xorg, firefox, chroot

I thought to start an isolated Firefox instance in a chroot, but it always crashes my X Server. I tried with different chroot environments (raring, trusty), and tried schroot and plain chroot too.

`/proc`, `/sys`, `/dev`, `/dev/pts` are bind-mounted into the chroot jail, as it is done automatically by schroot.

I have no idea what may cause this. When it happens, the X server restarts and I get back to the Unity login prompt, and when I log in again, Ubuntu asks me to send 3 crash reports.

The command I use to start Firefox is:

```
DISPLAY=:0 firefox &
```

Comment: Can you post the output of strace? `DISPLAY=:0 strace -ostrace.out firefox` creates a file `strace.out`. Post these contents somewhere, maybe we find out what happens with firefox.